# local passport.js authentication with orchestrate.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport-local, passport.js

Does anyone know of a tutorial/resources for setting up local passport.js authentication using Orchestrate to store my users? All of the resources I am finding use MongoDB and for my project we have to use Orchestrate. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Orchestrate works with promises and passport.js uses callback and I am having difficulty figuring out how to get the two to work together.

Answer (score 1):

Orchestrate has actually put together a tutorial demonstrating this in the time since you've asked this. I hope this helps.

[Build User Authentication WIth Node.js, Express, Passport and Orchestrate](https://orchestrate.io/blog/2014/06/26/build-user-authentication-with-node-js-express-passport-and-orchestrate/)